# Change label without having id in jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable with Search option. But I wanted to change label name with filter. I pasted below code from Browser Console but how can I change label name from Search to filter?

```
<div class="dataTables_filter" id="Register_filter">
    <label>Search: <input type="text">
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: What do mean by without having an id? No id on the label? No id on `div.datatables_filter`? Or no id anywhere?

Comment: Are you using this Datatables plugin? https://datatables.net/

Comment: @jonmrich Yes I a having datatable plugin.

Comment: Then see my answer below and that'll work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using the Datatables jquery plugin, you need this:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "language": {
    "search": "Filter records:"
  }
} );
```

Specifically, add the language part to your table initiation.

Comment: Well spotted on the use of Datatables. This is by far the best answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping I am newbie to datatable so didn't had idea about that. Appreciate that.